# Show that any orthogonal matrix has determinant 1 or -1

Tags: matrices, determinant

Hello fellow users of this forum:

Show that for any orthogonal matrix Q, either det(Q)=1 or -1.

Thanks

Comment: Hello fellow user, please search before asking.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong with using the transpose, but here it goes.

Since $Q$ is orthogonal, $QQ^T = I = Q^TQ$ by definition. Using the fact that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$, we have $\det(I) = 1 = \det(QQ^T) = \det(Q) \det(Q^T) = \det(Q) \det(Q) = [\det(Q)]^2$.

Since we have $[\det(Q)]^2 = 1$, then $\det(Q) = \pm \sqrt{1} = \pm 1$.

Comment: Very nice and neat proof. Thank you Xoque55

Comment: To see why $x^2=1$ implies $x=\pm 1$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4234231/572841) answer.