# Prove that the cross product of two vectors is a vector

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations, cross-product

I define a vector as any object $(a_i,a_j, a_k)$ such that it transforms the same way as the coordinates themselves. That is if $x'_i = R_{ij}x_j$, then $a'_i = R_{ij}a_j$ (using the Einstein convention of summing over repeated indices). Please correct me if this is not a proper definition.

I now want to take the cross product of two vectors, $\vec{c} = \vec{a}\times \vec{b}$ and prove (by this definition) that the output is also a vector. Using the Levi-Civita symbol, we have

$c'_i = R_{ij}c_j = det(R) R_{ij}\epsilon_{jlm}a_l b_m$

But this should somehow be the same as the cross product of the transformed $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. That is $c'_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a'_jb'_k = \epsilon_{ijk}R_{jl} a_l R_{km}b_m$

How do I reconcile these two? I know I should get $\rm{det(R)}$ in the second expression somehow but I can't see how to express it in this notation.

Comment: Actually, from the point of view of transformation properties, the cross product is not really a vector, but rather a “pseudovector”: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector. Or better, if you want to avoid that mess: use the *bivector* $a \wedge b$ instead.

Comment: Doesn't the det(R) take care of the pseudovector-ness of the output? In your link, it also says that $Rv_1 \times Rv_2 = det(R) R(v_1 \times v_2)$. I just can't see how to prove that statement using index notation.

Comment: Well, if you include the determinant, then yes. But you need to assume that $R$ is an orthogonal matrix too, maybe that's what's causing you trouble? (And then $\det R= \pm 1$.)

Comment: I see your point. I've edited the question now. The trouble I'm having is to express det(R) in index notation and show the equivalence.

Comment: "Please correct me if this is not a proper definition." - [It can be extended to a proper definition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768056/237923).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\mathbf c = \mathbf a \times \mathbf b$. Then, since $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are vectors and $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is a rank $3$ tensor, \begin{align*}
a_i' &= R_{ij} a_j \\
b_i' &= R_{ij} b_j \\
\varepsilon_{ijk}' &= R_{ip}R_{jq}R_{kr} \varepsilon_{pqr}.
\end{align*}
Now under a coordinate transformation, \begin{align*}
c_i& = \varepsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k \\
\implies c_i' &= \varepsilon_{ijk}' a_j' b_k' \\
&= R_{ip} R_{jq} R_{kr} \varepsilon_{pqr }R_{jm}a_m R_{kn}b_n \\
&= R_{ip} \delta_{qm} \delta_{rn} \varepsilon_{pqr} a_m b_n \tag{$*$} \\
&= R_{ip} \varepsilon_{pqr}a_q b_r \\
&= R_{ip} c_p,
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ follows since $R_{jq} R_{jm} = [\mathbf R^T]_{qj} \left[\mathbf R\right]_{jm} = \left[\mathbf R^T \mathbf T\right]_{qm} = \delta_{qm}$.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I reconcile these two?

First of all, I would like to emphasize that in general $Ma\times Mb\neq M(a\times b)$ for an invertible matrix $M$. If $M$ is orthogonal (i.e. $MM{}^t=1$), then$$M(a\times b)=(\det{M})(Ma\times Mb)$$
(see the proof below). Note that $\det M=\pm 1$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1172810/572841) is a proof), so we can equivalently write the determinant on the LHS of the equation. Hence we obtain $Ma\times Mb=M(a\times b)$ if $M$ is orthogonal and $\det M=1$.

### **Proof**:

Set
$$\forall i\in\{1,2,3\}:v_i:=\begin{pmatrix}M_{1i}\\M_{2i}\\M_{3i}\end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\det{M}=\epsilon_{ijk}\det(v_1|v_2|v_3)=\det(v_i|v_j|v_k)=\epsilon_{pqr}M_{ip}M_{jq}M_{kr}$$
where in the last step we used the Leibniz formula and hence
$$\forall k:(\det M)(Ma\times Mb)_k=(\det M)\epsilon_{ijk}(Ma)_i(Mb)_j=\epsilon_{pqr}M_{ip}M_{jq}M_{kr}M_{i\beta}a_\beta M_{j\alpha}b_\alpha\\
=\epsilon_{pqr}\underbrace{M_{ip}M_{i\beta}}_{=\delta_{p\beta}}\underbrace{M_{jq}M_{j\alpha}}_{=\delta_{q\alpha}}M_{kr}a_\beta b_\alpha=M_{kr}\epsilon_{pqr}a_pb_q=M_{kr}\epsilon_{pqr}a_pb_q=M_{kr}(a\times b)_r=(M(a\times b))_k$$